# Grapesjs custom storage as plug-in, not getting options and getting error for blocks section

Tags: javascript, grapesjs

I'm having some issues trying to load content using a custom storage manager as a plugin, that's the only way it works according this: https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/issues/2526

I need to pass the data to the load method, I'm trying to use the plugin options , but I get an empty object, also my custom storage plugin is making the newsltter preset to cause an error, not really sure why, I just want to get the custom storage working:

heres the error I get:

```
grapes.min.js?a826:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined
```

I created this sandbox for you guys to check the empty options issue that I mentioned
https://codesandbox.io/s/grapesjs-3ywko

any help would be awesome